# cumulative sum of number of records grouped by week

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, group-by, aggregate

I have the following database schema

```
ID  creation_date
1      2019-06-03
2      2019-06-04
3      2019-06-04
4      2019-06-10
5      2019-06-11
```

I need to find out the total size of the table group by week. The output I am looking for is something like

```
year   week number_of_records
2019    23      3
2019    24      5
```

I am writing the following query which only gives me number of record created in each week

```
> select year(creation_date) as year, weekofyear(creation_date) as week,
> count(id) from input group by year, week;
```

Output I get is

```
year   week number_of_records
2019    23      3
2019    24      2
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look to *window (or analytic) functions*.
Unlike aggregate functions, window functions preserve resulting rows and facilitate operations related to them. When using `order by` in `over` clause, windowing is done from first row to current row according to specified order, which is exactly what you need.

```
select year, week, sum(number_of_records) over (order by year, week)
from (
  select year(creation_date) as year, weekofyear(creation_date) as week,
  count(id) as number_of_records
  from input group by year, week
) your_sql
```

I guess you will also need to reset sum for each year, which I leave as exercise for you (hint: `partition` clause).

Answer (score 0):

For versions prior to 8.0...

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE my_table
(ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,creation_date DATE NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1    ,  '2019-06-03'),
(2     , '2019-06-04'),
(3     , '2019-06-04'),
(4      ,'2019-06-10'),
(5      ,'2019-06-11');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT a.yearweek
, @i:=@i+a.total running
FROM
(SELECT DATE_FORMAT(x.creation_date,'%x-%v') yearweek
, COUNT(*) total
FROM my_table x
GROUP BY yearweek
)a
JOIN (SELECT @i:=0) vars
ORDER BY a.yearweek;

| yearweek | running |
| -------- | ------- |
| 2019-23  | 3       |
| 2019-24  | 5       |

---
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gFQCHxakcm4PgoZbroGnLF/0)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want a cumulative sum.  You can do this with window functions directly in an aggregation query:

```
select year(creation_date) as year, weekofyear(creation_date) as week,
       count(*) as number_of_starts,
       sum(count(*)) over (order by min(creation_date)) as number_of_records
from input
group by year, week;
```

Comment: You forgot to `PARTITION` your sum(count(*)) by YEAR(creation_date) - otherwise the running total [keeps increasing over the years](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e42704718fde5e18ea15bbdfdbcec3ba) which is probably not what the OP wants?